# Τransfer data through AC signal

Tags: arduino, ac, communication

I would like to transmit 1 byte through an AC line from an arduino to another which is power by the AC line. This is something like what I want to do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcm6jS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, let me explain what I have thought. The first arduino detects the zero crossing using the opto-isolator and after that for half a sine wave triggers the triac 8 times to form a byte inside the half wave. The second arduino, which is powered by the AC line also reads this wave and when it detects the encoded wave does something with that information. So there are some questions:

- Can that be done?
- Will there be problems?
- Are there any other ways to pass small info through the AC line without using off the shelf products?
- Can that be done for more bytes?

*The specific example will be used to control a light bulb and an led strip both attached to the second arduino using a rotary encoder attached to the first.*

Comment: Once a TRIAC triggers it can not shut off until the next zero crossing. This will prevent you from stuffing a byte into a half wave.

Comment: Are all TRIACs work the same way? Are there other components to do the job?

Comment: Yes all TRIACs work the same way. There are some products that can pass signals over AC. For example TDA5051A home automation modem.

Comment: As vini says, once you fire a triac it isn't until the current drops to ~0 that it opens. You could switch between two different firing angles to form a bit stream, 0, +45 for example.

Comment: you could delay the triac a few micros, maybe 0-8 to transfer 3 bits, if you can measure the delay accurately. there's probably lots of ways to send 1-2 bits per period using reverse-biased or upon zero-cross pulses (or not) that can be detected before being filtered out for power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit might work, but you probably can't mix data and power. Since you'll be dimming the power line for data bits. One bit per fundamental cycle because you can't turn the triac off until a zero crossing.

PLC works by injecting a high frequency carrier into the power line. It uses a capacitive coupling and a bandpass filter. Look at the example circuits in the [TDA5051A](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA5051A.pdf) datasheet of how they inject and receive the 132.5 Khz signal.

Comment: I would go with the PLC modem but I need to pass the data from inside the key switch of the light. So, I have access only to one of the two wires of the AC line. I think that isn't possible using a PLC modem, am I wrong?

Comment: @ChristosMitsis No, add extra wires or go for a wireless solution. (eg: kinetic switches)